# How to display fullscreen(centerCrop) image on android WebView?

Tags: android, css, image, webview

I would like to load an image into android `WebView` and make it like `ImageView`'s `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

I have tried http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/. 
All work great on PC's firefox but not on Android WebView. It always stretch the image!! Even I take this `websetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);`  into account but nothing changed.

Only the CSS3 method almost done. Because the image is background but not an element. However, I encounter [Using html/css3 and WebView to scale an image to the screen... get a white screen before the image loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955563/using-html-css3-and-webview-to-scale-an-image-to-the-screen-get-a-white-scree#comment39476324_7955563) . Also the workaround work great on firefox but not in android.

Do I have no choice but to use `ImageView` ?

Comment: Post the url of one of the image that you are trying to display, please.

Comment: @valbertos, really, I don't care what the image is. I would like to know how to adjust html/setting of `WebView` to make an image show fullscreen and behave like `centerCrop`.

Comment: Android WebView are based on Chromium since KitKat, or WebKit for version below. Please try with Chrome or Safari to use webkit.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

For the portrait mode, and when image height is less than image width;

```
  _webview.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
 _webview.setInitialScale((int) (((imageHeight-webViewHeight)/imageHeight)*100));

    String html1=   new String ("</head> <body style=\"background:url(file:///android_res/drawable/diego.jpg) no-repeat center center\"></body> </html>");

    _webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html1, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Tried. Not work. It just show the image with origin size an center horizontally only. It does not scale to centerCrop and not really center.

Comment: Edited my answer, try please.

Comment: It only consider the image height. The [css3 method mentioned](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) is much much better because it does not depend on image size and scale to fit the screen like centerCrop.

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
  background-size: cover;
}
```